# Activating/deactivating virtualenv in a python script

Tags: python, shell, virtualenv, openshift

I'm using OpenShift, and I'm using the custom hooks. Mainly:

- start (application start)
- stop  (application stop)
- pre_build
- post_deploy

For reasons of I've-already-tried, I'm not using 3rd-party cartridges serving python/nginx (It gives me several errors out of this topic).

So I had to stick on manually installing nginx, and ensuring that starts and stops accordingly.

Now: My application uses nginx because I need websockets, and the best library I found is fairly modern. So for my application I must use `gunicorn` and `django-gevent-websockets`.

For many language issues, I rejected using shell script but instead I used python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
...
```

And, after doing complex tasks, I run by `os.system` many commands with the following logic:

- start the virtual environment
- install a recent gunicorn (if it's not installed)
- install the websockets library (if it's not installed)
- leave the virtual environment
- pkill httpd processes
- start nginx

Always echoing those commands to console (`print`ing them). But I found an error:

```
sh: command deactivate not found.
```

This means: at the moment of executing that command, somehow we were not in the virtualenv. I don't know if I'm right with this, but seems that `os.system` creates a different environment for each call, so: after the `start the virtualenv` step, I'm not anymore in the virtual env.

**Question**: How can I preserve the shell context across calls, so the `activate` call has effect in subsequent system calls? This means: I want to be able to put those packages in the virtualenv, and execute related stuff.

This OpenShift application uses a Python cartridge (shipped with Apache).